# Search Field for Document Library Webpart

Tags: document-library, search

I use SharePoint Online which comes with Office 365.  I would like to add a search field into the document library web part (rather than needing to open the library by itself).  Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend using your list view pages to utilize all the OOB features like (Filters, Searching, and etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing the Web Part:

1. Edit the web part
2. Under Miscellaneous
3. Tick Display Search Box

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you change to classic , yes but online doesn't have it

Comment: Some of the modern parts are a step back in features.